# Hot to use Tornado to get the url parameter?

Tags: python, url, tornado

Here is an example

**www.example.com/abc/def**

I just wanna get **"abc"** and **"def"** without **"/"**.Is it possible?

Is it nice if  I used **self.request.uri** and got **"abc/def"** first ,Then turn it to an string ,and  using **split('/')** to split it so I can get **"abc"** and **"def"**

I don't feel comfortable with this solution. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexps when adding handlers to have Tornado parse the URL for you:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, a, b):
        self.write("a:%s b:%s" % (a, b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```